# Magento 2 - How to move the product price block before addtocart button?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, design, theme-overriding

I am using custom theme and trying to move the `"product.info.price"` block before the `addtocart button`.

I have tried, direct into `addtocart.phtml` file but not working.

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
```

> app\design\frontend\my_package\my_theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml

**If I used :**

```
<move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.addtocart" />
```

Then it moves the price but it only appears on simple products without custom options.

**If I used :**

```
<move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.addtocart.additional" />
```

Then it moves the price but it only appears on simple products with custom options.

**So,** How I can show the price block for both **`simple product`** and **`simple product with custom options`**.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to below location

> Magento_root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view

Copy file with Name **addtocart.phtml** & paste it to below location in your theme

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view

Put the below code into the file above this `<div class="actions">` present at around line no.31 .

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render',
                  "product.price.final",
                    [
                        'data' => [
                            'price_render' => 'product.price.render.default',
                            'price_type_code' => 'final_price',
                            'zone' => 'item_view'
                        ]
                   ]
                  )
          ->toHtml();?>
```

Now go to the below location

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/

Put the below code into the file with name `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <referenceBlock name="product.price.final" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Note: Put your cache disabled or run the below command while you are
>   doing this changes
>
> ```
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works well. Please upvote this question so other can get help.

Comment: This work for me, but how to add the Incl Tax and Excl Tax text after the each price.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you may need to add your code in a separate layout file for the respective product type.

Try creating `catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml` file for configurable product and then add the below code in it.

```
<move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.addtocart.additional" />
```

**Note:** *Please check all product pages by product type, there is a default separate layout for bundle products. So if it is not working for any product type you can add a separate layout file for that product type like above for configurable products **also the referenceBlock/referenceContainer name may vary for product type***.

Comment: I am working on simple product and simple product with custom options not configurable products.

Comment: It is not working for simple products without custom options

Comment: you have to add for both destinations, for  configurable add `product.info.addtocart.additional` and for simple  add `product.info.addtocart`

Comment: How it related with  configurable? Please explain. Even working only for simple products

Comment: then you can do it vice versa, add `product.info.addtocart.additional` code  in `catalog_product_view.xml` and create `catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml` and add code for destination `product.info.addtocart`

Comment: In same XML, how can we move same element two times??

Comment: it is not possible to move same element twice in same `xml` it will consider the last move for it.

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI if you read the comments above, I have asked to create separate xml based on product type and Not to add in same xml

Answer (score 3):

Follow Below given two instructions

1.Go to the below file

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/

Open/create file with name `catalog_product_view.xml`

Put below code into it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.addtocart" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

2.Go to the below file

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/Package/theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/layout/

Open/create file with name `catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml`

Put below code into it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.addtocart.additional" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Note: Put your cache disabled or run the below command while you are
>   doing this changes
>
> ```
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```

Comment: I am working on simple product and simple product with custom options not configurable products.

Comment: Is it okay for you to have the `product.info.extrahint` below the **Add-to cart**  button & above the **`Add-to-wishlist`,`Add-to-Compare`,`E-mail`** ?

Comment: I have already applied it and it works but I do not want to use it

Comment: It place the price after addtocart button.

Comment: You want to move only price or you want to move the price with stock & sku details also?

Comment: Only price section before the add to cart button in both cases as mention in question.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT follow the instructions above if you are using Magento2 EE

"Copy file with Name addtocart.phtml & paste it to below location in your theme"

this will break your catalog product page with an error
"An element with a "product.price.final" ID already exists."

instead can try moving it like this

```
    <move element="product.price.final" destination="product.info.addtocart" before="-"/>
```

and then using CSS / flex grid you can do a column-reverse and adjust the sort order top to bottom for example.. the other solution is just REPEATING the "product.price.final" in a template causing other layout XML implementation to become a duplicate and error