# How to remove add to wishlist and email in product detail page?

Tags: magento2.3, products

I want to remove add to wishlist and email in product detail page. How to do that?

[image]

Can anyone please point me on how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to remove the wishlist and send email to friend functionality from your website or only from the product details page?

Comment: I want to do it only on product detail page

Comment: Are you using any custom theme on your website?

Comment: No, we have extended the luma theme

Comment: OK, do you've calalog_product_view.xml in Magento_Catalog/layout folder in your theme?

Comment: yes, I have put the below codes on that file but still it's not removing. Can I remove it from css instead?

Comment: I've tried the same on my website and it is working fine. I can share the CSS way to remove them from the page if you want. If yes, then please let me know.

Comment: I have done it from css. Anyway can you please share your css so that I come to know whether the thing i followed is correct or wrong

Comment: OK sure, sharing with you in a while.

Comment: Check my answer.
Also, you need to run php bin/magento s:s:d -f after the xml file changes.

Comment: @sumit, one more question, how to move the product price below quantity and above add to cart button in product detail page.

Comment: Check this link @Siva, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214720/magento-2-how-to-move-the-product-price-block-before-addtocart-button

Comment: @Sumit, I have tried that but it wasn't worked as expected. Can you please guide me?

Comment: It should work as explained in the given answer.

I'm not sure but it seems like the issue is with your theme's products page because of the default changes are works with Luma theme but not with your theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the wishlist and share in email with adding below code in your `/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` file before the body tag end.

```
<referenceBlock name="view.addto.wishlist" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.mailto" remove="true" />
```

Also, if you want to remove them with CSS then you can use below code in your CSS file.

```
.catalog-product-view .product-addto-links .action.towishlist,
.catalog-product-view .product-social-links .action.mailto.friend{
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to remove the send email to friend and wishlist feature throughout the website, then you can do that by setting configuration in the Magento admin.

**For wishlist:**

1. Go to the Admin sidebar, click on “Stores” and then select “Configuration” under “Settings”.
2. After the selection of “Configuration”, you need to choose “Wish List” under “Customers”.
3. Then explore the General Options section and change “Enabled” to “No”.

**For sending an email to a friend:**

1. Go to the Admin sidebar, click on “Stores” and then select “Configuration” under “Settings”.
2. After the selection of “Configuration”, you need to choose “Email to a Friend” under “Catalog”.
3. Set Enabled to No.

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

**To Remove Wishlist And Email in Detail Page**

> In Your Theme Create `catalog_product_view.xml` file Under the
>   `app/design/frontend/Vendorname/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

**Add This :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="view.addto.wishlist" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.mailto" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I have tried this but still both the wishlist and email is displaying in detail page. I have tried clean cache, indexing.

Answer (score 0):

On your custom Theme:
Make a Folder:
Magento_Catalog/layout
Inside there you make a file called catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.mailto" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="view.addto.wishlist" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a file

> Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="view.addto.wishlist" remove="true" /> 
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, you can actually now remove Wishlist and Email products functionality via XML file. Wishlist and Email products block is defined in 
`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

and you can remove it by adding a default.xml file to your theme in: `<theme_dir>/Magento_Catalog/layout/calalog_product_view.xml`

inside which you remove your block as follows:

**Add This :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="view.addto.wishlist" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.mailto" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceBlock name="view.addto.wishlist" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.mailto" remove="true" />
```